# Spring KafkaListener: How to know when it's ready

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have a simple Spring Boot application which reads from Kafka and writes to Kafka. I wrote a `SpringBootTest` using an `EmbeddedKafka` to test all that.

The main problem is: Sometimes the test fails because the test sends the Kafka message too early. That way, the message is already written to Kafka before the Spring application (or its `KafkaListener` to be precise) is ready. Since the listener reads from the `latest` offset (I do not want to change any config for my test - except bootstrap.servers), it will not receive all messages in that test.

Does anyone have an idea how I could know inside the test, that the `KafkaListener` is ready to receive messages?

Only way I could think of is waiting until `/health` comes available but I have no idea whether I can be sure that this implies the `KafkaListener` to be ready at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` instance, then it is very easy to use `org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(Object container, int partitions)`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/test/utils/ContainerTestUtils.html

e.g. calling `ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container, 1);` in your Test setup will block until the container has gotten 1 partition assigned.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just read about `@PostConstruct` and it turns out that you can easily use this also within the test:

```
@PostConstruct
public void checkApplicationReady() {
    applicationReady = true;
}
```

Now I added an `@Before` method to wait until that flag is set to true.

So far this seems to work very nicely!

Comment: Nope, the issue still occurs.

Comment: Current idea is implementing `ConsumerSeekAware` and setting a boolean when `onPartitionsAssigned` was called. This is stable now (at least after ~100 runs)